# Using phpexcel insert into web api

Tags: php, yii2, phpexcel, yii2-advanced-app

I am using phpexcel to send student record via excel in bulk and i want to post to api in json format.my output is below but i want in the format like below from which the api can save the each data in database.
My Controller:

```
$import = new ImportExcel();
    if ($import->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //upload path global parameters
        Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/upload/excel/';
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($import, 'import');
        $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $file;
        $file->saveAs($path);
        //  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
        try {
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path);
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        //  Get worksheet dimensions
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
        $worksheet  = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName('Sheet1');
        $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
        //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            //  Read a row of data into an array
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                NULL,
                TRUE,
                FALSE);

            var_dump(json_encode($rowData));


        }
    }
```

OutPut:

```
string(70) "[["name","address","class","section","guardian","contact us","email"]]" string(107) "[["sugam pradhan","rambazar,pokhara-10",10,"A","jayandra kumar rajbhandari",61431910,"suyog844@gmail.com"]]" string(105) "[["Bill gurung","rambazar,pokhara-10",10,"A","jayandra kumar rajbhandari",61431910,"suyog844@gmail.com"]]" string(107) "[["Bimal poudelq","rambazar,pokhara-10",10,"A","jayandra kumar rajbhandari",61431910,"suyog844@gmail.com"]]" string(101) "[["Dam sir","rambazar,pokhara-10",10,"A","jayandra kumar rajbhandari",61431910,"suyog844@gmail.com"]]"
```

I want to post in :

```
[{'school_id':3,'name':'name1','image':'image1','guardian_name':'guardian_name1','address':'address1','contact_no':'111','email':'email1@mail.com','blood_grp':'A','d_o_b':'2001-01-01','class_id':1,'section_id':2,'roll_no':'1','enrolled_date':'2010-01-01','is_active':0},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map first row as keys as far as I understood.

```
        $row = 1; $result = [];
        $keys = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                NULL,
                TRUE,
                FALSE);
        //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            //  Read a row of data into an array
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                NULL,
                TRUE,
                FALSE);

            $result[] = array_combine($keys,$rowData);

        }
        var_dump($result);
```

This way you will get what you need if 1st row is keys for your array.